# Authenticate Angular App Without User Credentials With OAuth and IdentityServer4

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4

I have an Angular App that communicates with an Asp.net Core API. It is a public app meaning a user does not specify a username and password to use it.

I want to use IdentityServer4 to protect the API from direct manipulation however. When looking at the various Credential Flows on IS4, Client Credentialing looked like the right fit. However all the posts out there talk about Authorization Code Flow.

Is this the best route to go down or is this a bad idea? How might I accomplish this?

Comment: The code flow sends the user to IdentityServer and redirects it back to the client after login. With client credentials there is no roundtrip, which makes it more important that the client can keep a secret. In your case you may want to implement a [custom grant type](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html) that requires a roundtrip, but doesn't require to verify the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main question here is "the quality of trust". In general it's not possible to make a public js client trusted at all. Anyone can open a console in a browser, copy a request, paste it into curl or postman and call the api. If you however want just to block direct access to *get* methods without bearer token in a header, then pure *Client Credentials* is more than enough. Otherwise you have to implement something special, such as a totally *custom grant*, or simpler a `CustomTokenRequestValidator`, which will be called from within a normal flow (including Client Credentials) and where you can perform some additional checks (both approaches referenced [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1156)).

Comment: Would it maybe be easier to accomplish what I want to do by sticking with SSL and Cors (api and app will run on two subdomains of same domain)?

Comment: Cors could help against calls from js. If you need additional protection against curious users (copy-pasting get requests into browser address bar), it'd better to combine cors with a lightweight bearer token (or domain-wide cookie)